# How to use Project's Assembly information when building NuGet package using MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

How can I use the assembly information from the project to pass and use by NuGet package when creating NuGet package using MSBuild.

[Assembly Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzyMX.png)

```
</Project>
<PropertyGroup>
   <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>Test</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion Condition=""></PackageVersion>
    <Title>Testing</Title>
    <Authors>Hugh</Authors>
    <PackageIcon>Hugh.png</PackageIcon>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Description>test</Description>
    <PackageTags>test</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Update.</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright © 2021 </copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\test.png" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I want the NuGet Package ID to set as Assembly Title, Description as Assembly Description, Author as Company, PackageVersion as Assembly Version and so on.

```
  <Target Name="RetrieveIdentities">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity
        AssemblyFiles="$(MyAssemblies)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Assemblies"
          ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <Message Text="Files: %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)"/>
  </Target>
```

I have tried using the above target but couldn't succeed and not sure to use or reference %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version) in Package Version under PropertyGroup for NuGet package.

Please advise ?

Comment: The `GetAssemblyIdentity` task doesn't retrieve all the AssemblyInfo. It only provides `Version`, `PublicKeyToken`, and `Culture` which are used for referencing a strong named assembly.

Comment: Is there any other task that can be used ? Or can I have Version number using GetAssemblyIdentity task and the other details specified in the project file ? Can you please provide some working example that gets version number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reusing MSBuild variables is enough for syncing `AssemblyTitle` with `PackageId` (as far as naming restrictions allow) and `Company` with `Authors` etc.. No targets required.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyTitle>Some Title</AssemblyTitle>
        <Company>Some Company</Company>
        <Description>Some Description</Description>

        <PackageId>$(AssemblyTitle.Replace(" ", "_"))</PackageId>
        <Authors>$(Company)</Authors>

        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

When building this with

```
dotnet build -p:Version=1.2.3
```

(or adding the `Version` property to the csproj),
the build will by default use the given `Version` as both package version and assembly version.

The package then looks like this, which should address every requirement from your question:
[image]